# forEach from array only adding last value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have a function with params and I am doing a forEach loop to add all the values from the loop.

```
const data = (sd) => Object.entries(obj).map(([k, g]) => ({
            ['name']: k,
            ['data']: g.map(entry => entry[sd]),
            ['type']: sd
        }));
```

let arr = ['abc', 'xyz'];

```
let x;
arr.forEach(y => {
  x = [...data(y)];
});
console.log(x);
```

If I do this, I only the values for `xyz`.

If I do:

```
let x;
arr.forEach(y => {
  x.push(data(y));
});
console.log(x);
```

I am getting `[Array(15), Array(15)]`. I want the merged array of both arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doing good, the only thing you are missing is to add the `...x` in the first method. and adding spread operator in the second method.
Both the method should work for you do it like this.

```
let x = [];
arr.forEach(y => {
  x = [...x, ...data(y)];
});
console.log(x);
```

and

```
let x = [];
arr.forEach(y => {
  x.push(...data(y));
});
console.log(x);
```